# Trying to get Paperclip to refresh or reprocess not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, paperclip

I have over time, changed the size for thumbs of the class Deal. Through these changes, users were uploading to the site, so there are few people who have different sized thumbs. I wanted to reprocress or refresh these, so I went to into my root and typed:

```
rake paperclip:refresh class=Deal
```

Did nothing for the thumb sizes.. Then I in script/console :

> Deal.find(987).reprocess!

Returned this :

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `reprocess!' for #<Deal:0xb68a0988>
from /data/HQ_Channel/releases/20100607130346/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:260:in `method_missing'
from (irb):7
```

My deal class is this :

```
=> Deal(id: integer, organization_id: integer, deal: string, value: string, what: string, description: string, image_file_name: string, image_content_type: string, image_file_size: integer, image_updated_at: datetime, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, deal_image_file_name: string, deal_image_content_type: string, deal_image_file_size: integer, deal_image_uploaded_at: datetime)
```

What can i do to have it reprocess the original to make the thumb the correct size in the current thumb size params?

**UPDATE:** I have found the **attachment.rb** included with Paperclip. What's interesting is that methods like `.save`, and `.updated_at` work. But `reprocess!` and a few other methods do not. Does anything smell obviously out of place?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Got it!

It's because paperclip isn't relative to the Model's object, but rather the Model's object's image. So written proper, it would work like this :

```
Model.find(#).image.reprocess!
```

Comment: Model.find_each { |thing| thing.image.reprocess! }

Answer (score 12):

You can also use the included Rake task:

```
$ rake paperclip:refresh CLASS=Deal
```

See [Paperclip Wiki](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation)